# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown Item Highlighting Not Stretching Full Width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 with React to implement dropdown menus. When an item within a dropdown is selected or hovered, I want the highlighted background color to stretch the full width of the dropdown. However, only the last item in the dropdown list stretches fully, while the others don't.

Here's the CSS I've tried:

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
    padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover,
.nav-item .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item.active {
    background-color: #2596be !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Here's the js:

```
return (
        <li className={isOpen ? "nav-item dropdown show" : "nav-item dropdown"} ref={dropdownRef}>
            <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id={id} role="button" onClick={toggleDropdown} aria-expanded={isOpen}>
                {label}
            </a>
            {isOpen && (
                <ul className="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby={id}>
                    {items.map(item => (
                        <li key={item.id}>
                            <a
                                className={`dropdown-item ${selectedItem && selectedItem.id === item.id ? 'active' : ''}`}
                                href="#"
                                id={item.id}
                                onClick={() => handleItemClick(item)}
                            >
                                {item.label}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </li>
    );
```

[preview #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu23J.png)
[preview #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIU4d.png)

I've tried adjusting the padding and margin for the .dropdown-item class and also increased the specificity of my custom styles to override Bootstrap defaults. The issue persists.

How can I ensure that the highlighted background color for each dropdown item spans the full width of the dropdown menu consistently for all items?

Comment: It appears that the anchors are not block-level. Do you have CSS somewhere that changes `dropdown-item` from `display: block`? It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.